# Keep .NET Console App running as service Raspberry Pi Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I have a console app in .NET 6/C# and I configured it to run on Ubuntu 20.04 (Raspberry PI) as service under /etc/systemd/system. If I run the app manually such as sudo dotnet myapp.dll then it stays up until you kill it.

However when it runs as a service, it seems to restart every few seconds and the only clue I found is "**Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.**"

When I change to Console.Read instead of Console.ReadKey, it still restarts.
To give more context of the console app, it waits to read RFID tags. Here some snippet of the code.

```
            reader.Start();
            // Perform the Complex Operations on a separate thread
            Task.Run(() => performComplexOperationsOnSeenTagsAsync(reader));

            Console.WriteLine("Please put a tag in front of the antenna and Press Enter to Exit!");
            
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It is basically telling you that things running as a service don't have a console.  So you can't write or read from it.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - Got it. Any other option? The console app, listens to RFID tags being scanned and my program processes them.

Comment: So what do you need to have console?  Don't you just want it doing a loop looking for an RFID tag?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I just need it stay up running and look for RFID tags, when a person puts a tag in front of the reader (Which is something it already does). So console only works then if I run it manually.

Comment: Yes, so just have it in a infinite loop, unless the service is stopped.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I will try that. Thanks you helped me get a better understanding.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - Hey, I was able to test the while(true) {} loop on Ubuntu as a Service. The problem is the reader is not reading RFID tags. Not sure if its because the while loops continuously and the program doesnt have time to process it? If you have some suggestions, would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try putting a delay in the loop, so it waits a bit before trying to read again, also try debugging by attaching to the process to see where the problem is.